# In SQL Server can I insert multiple nodes into XML from a table?

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, insert, xquery

I want to generate some XML in a stored procedure based on data in a table.

The following insert allows me to add many nodes but they have to be hard-coded or use variables (sql:variable):

```
SET @MyXml.modify('
      insert
         <myNode>
            {sql:variable("@MyVariable")}
         </myNode>
      into (/root[1]) ')
```

So I could loop through each record in my table, put the values I need into variables and execute the above statement.

But is there a way I can do this by just combining with a select statement and avoiding the loop?

**Edit** I have used `SELECT FOR XML`  to do similar stuff before but I always find it hard to read when working with a hierarchy of data from multiple tables. I was hoping  there would be something using the `modify` where the XML generated is more explicit and more controllable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried **nesting** FOR XML PATH scalar valued functions? 
With the nesting technique, you can brake your SQL into very managable/readable elemental pieces

Disclaimer: the following, while adapted from a working example, has not itself been literally tested

Some reference links for the general audience

- http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107(SQL.90).aspx
- http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189885(SQL.90).aspx

The simplest, lowest level nested node example

Consider the following invocation

```
DECLARE  @NestedInput_SpecificDogNameId int
SET @NestedInput_SpecificDogNameId = 99
SELECT [dbo].[udfGetLowestLevelNestedNode_SpecificDogName] 
(@NestedInput_SpecificDogNameId)
```

Let's say had udfGetLowestLevelNestedNode_SpecificDogName had been written without the FOR XML PATH clause, and for @NestedInput_SpecificDogName = 99 it returns the single rowset record:

```
@SpecificDogNameId  DogName
99                  Astro
```

But with the FOR XML PATH clause,

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udfGetLowestLevelNestedNode_SpecificDogName
(
@NestedInput_SpecificDogNameId
)
    RETURNS XML
    AS
    BEGIN

        -- Declare the return variable here
        DECLARE @ResultVar XML

        -- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here
        SET @ResultVar =
            (
            SELECT 
                  @SpecificDogNameId as "@SpecificDogNameId",
                  t.DogName 
            FROM tblDogs t
            FOR XML PATH('Dog')
            )

        -- Return the result of the function
        RETURN @ResultVar

END
```

the user-defined function produces the following XML (the @ signs causes the SpecificDogNameId field to be returned as an attribute)

```
<Dog SpecificDogNameId=99>Astro</Dog>
```

Nesting User-defined Functions of XML Type

User-defined functions such as the above udfGetLowestLevelNestedNode_SpecificDogName can be nested to provide a powerful method to produce complex XML.

For example, the function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udfGetDogCollectionNode]()
    RETURNS XML
    AS
    BEGIN

        -- Declare the return variable here
        DECLARE @ResultVar XML

        -- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here
        SET @ResultVar =
            (
                SELECT  
                [dbo].[udfGetLowestLevelNestedNode_SpecificDogName]
                        (t.SpecificDogNameId)
                FROM tblDogs t

                FOR XML PATH('DogCollection') ELEMENTS
            )
        -- Return the result of the function
        RETURN @ResultVar

END
```

when invoked as

```
SELECT [dbo].[udfGetDogCollectionNode]()
```

might produce the complex XML node (given the appropriate underlying data)

```
<DogCollection>
    <Dog SpecificDogNameId="88">Dino</Dog>
    <Dog SpecificDogNameId="99">Astro</Dog>
</DogCollection>
```

From here, you could keep working upwards in the nested tree to build as complex an XML structure as you please

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udfGetAnimalCollectionNode]()
RETURNS XML
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @ResultVar XML

SET @ResultVar =
(
SELECT 
dbo.udfGetDogCollectionNode(),
dbo.udfGetCatCollectionNode()
FOR XML PATH('AnimalCollection'), ELEMENTS XSINIL
)

RETURN @ResultVar

END
```

when invoked as

```
SELECT [dbo].[udfGetAnimalCollectionNode]()
```

the udf might produce the more complex XML node (given the appropriate underlying data)

```
<AnimalCollection>
  <DogCollection>
    <Dog SpecificDogNameId="88">Dino</Dog>
    <Dog SpecificDogNameId="99">Astro</Dog>
  </DogCollection>
  <CatCollection>
    <Cat SpecificCatNameId="11">Sylvester</Cat>
    <Cat SpecificCatNameId="22">Tom</Cat>
    <Cat SpecificCatNameId="33">Felix</Cat>
  </CatCollection>
</AnimalCollection>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use sql:column instead of sql:variable. You can find detailed info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191214.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell a bit more about what exactly you are planning to do.
Is it simply generating XML data based on a content of the table 
or adding some data from the table to an existing xml structure?

There are [great series of articles](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Authors/Articles/Jacob_Sebastian/212008/) on the subject on XML in SQLServer written by Jacob Sebastian, it starts with the [basics of generating XML from the data in the table](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SS2K5+-+XML/3022/)